# Dynamic match in grep (double grep) - backreference?

Tags: regex, grep

From this output:

```
    2017-01-06 15:28:21,384 INFO  [py.com.interceptors.SecurityInterceptor] (default task-14) (#1dfp) {"id":"1dfp","method":"getImageById","actionURL":"/image/get/{imageId}","admin":"mgarcia"}
    2017-01-06 15:28:21,384 INFO  [py.com.SomeOtherClass] (default task-14) (#1dfp) something I don't even know why I wanna log 
more lines that not necessary have the same format
    2017-01-06 15:28:21,384 INFO  [py.com.SomeOtherClass] (default task-14) (#1111) something I don't even know why I wanna log 
more lines that not necessary have the same format
    2017-01-06 15:28:21,384 INFO  [py.com.SomeOtherClass] (default task-14) (#1111) something I don't even know why I wanna log
    2017-01-06 15:28:21,384 INFO  [py.com.SomeOtherClass] (default task-14) (#1dfp) something I don't even know why I wanna log
```

I want to get:

```
2017-01-06 15:28:21,384 INFO  [py.com.interceptors.SecurityInterceptor] (default task-14) (#**1dfp**) {"id":"1dfp","method":"getImageById","actionURL":"/image/get/{imageId}","admin":"mgarcia"}
2017-01-06 15:28:21,384 INFO  [py.com.SomeOtherClass] (default task-14) (#1dfp) something I don't even know why I wanna log
2017-01-06 15:28:21,384 INFO  [py.com.SomeOtherClass] (default task-14) (#1dfp) something I don't even know why I wanna log
```

All those lines that have (#1dfp), basically, only I don't know the value: (#1dfp) until i do grep '/image/get/{imageId}'

Is it possible to do it in a single line? like:

tail -f $log | grep 'some backreference or OR that would get me all the (#1dfp) by /image/get/{imageId}'

thanks!

Comment: can you post some more lines to get a clear example?

Comment: Why does not `grep "(#1dfp)" yourfile` work? What do you mean by combine two greps? Maybe you can give a few more example lines with the desired output?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thanks for your response, just updated the Q

Comment: @LarsFischer thanks for your response, just updated the Q

Comment: What is the rule to get `(#1dfp)` from a line that contains `/image/get/{imageId}` ? Is it always the second word enclosed in parens after the word enclosed in brackets or something?

Comment: @no_ripcord, there's only one line that matches both conditions `(#1dfp)` and `/image/get/{imageId}` in your input

Comment: Just updated the Q, hope it's more clear now. Thankyou MRs an MSs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk -F '[()]' 'index($0, "/image/get/{imageId}"){id=$4} $4 == id' file.log

2017-01-06 15:28:21,384 INFO  [py.com.interceptors.SecurityInterceptor] (default task-14) (#1dfp) {"id":"1dfp","method":"getImageById","actionURL":"/image/get/{imageId}","admin":"mgarcia"}
2017-01-06 15:28:21,384 INFO  [py.com.SomeOtherClass] (default task-14) (#1dfp) something I don't even know why I wanna log
2017-01-06 15:28:21,384 INFO  [py.com.SomeOtherClass] (default task-14) (#1dfp) something I don't even know why I wanna log
```

**How it works:**

- we are using `(` or `)` as input field separator
- `index($0, "/image/get/{imageId}")` find a line with text `/image/get/{imageId}` and then `id=$4` assigns 4th field to `id`
- Then `$4 == id` just prints all lines that have `$4` same as variable `id`

Comment: tried it but doens't work because there are lines that don't follow the exact pattern...

Comment: An answer will be as good as the information provided in question. You should update the question with more details or more sample.

Comment: you're right. just updated the Q. I'll add even more output, just don't want to make the Q long as hell, but it can contain also stacktraces and stuff

Comment: My given awk command above is still working with your updated sample data.